# Airflow task initiation issue

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We are running more then 150 dags in our production airflow environment and we facing task initiation issues very often. We are running airflow 1.7.2 with local executer mode hosted in google compute engine, Cloudsql as our metadb.

[image]

How to fix this issue? I have upgraded airflow into 1.8.2 but no luck. For the temporary solution, we are changing our dag name and start date to fix this issue. but this is not a solution. what is the solution for this issue? and Why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the airflow scheduler and webserver are working OK, but there is an issue with the airflow workers. If you review the airflow worker log, you may see an error there.